# How to get data by date from database to using codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to get data of last week. I try many ways but always get errors or nun results.

```
$query = "SELECT `toy1`,`toy2`
    FROM
      `tabel`
          WHERE `data1` != 'str' &&`data2` = 'str' && `date_row` >= '2014/12/08' AND `postdate` <= '2014/12/01' Limit 0,6";
     $q = $this->db->query($query);
          $rr = $q->result();
```

Comment: that query return minimum and maximum, not last week,

Comment: see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13215072/how-to-find-data-from-last-week-in-mysql might it is what you looking for.

Comment: what is your database schema?

Answer (score 0):

Your query operator to check greater and lesser is wrong. You need to check the below:

```
`date_row` <= '2014/12/08' AND `postdate` >= '2014/12/01'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->select('toy1,toy2');
$this->db->from('tabel');
$this->db->where('data1 !=','str');
$this->db->where('data2 !=','str');
$this->db->where('date_row >= ', date('Y/m/d', strtotime('-1 week')));
$this->db->where('postdate >= ', date('Y/m/d', strtotime('-1 week')));
$this->db->limit(7);
$query = $this->db->get();
if($query->num_rows > 0)
{
    $result = $query->result_array();
        // get your array
}
else
{
    echo 'no result';
}
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged and fall directly into Low Quality Posts queue.

Comment: As @VDohnal states; please feel free to explain your solution so OP can see what went wrong!

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following code. It will solve your problem.

```
$this->db->select('toy1,toy2');
$this->db->from('tabel');
$this->db->order_by('postdate','desc');
$this->db->limit(7);
$query = $this->db->get();
$result = $query->result_array();
```

$result variable have stored the last week data. Use the following code for print the data.

```
print '<pre>';
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$query =   SELECT * FROM "tablename" 
           WHERE "date" >= '2014-12-30' AND "date" <= '2014-12-01'
$q = $this->db->query($query);
$rr = $q->result();
```